# Finding minimum and maximum within a function

Tags: vector

I want to create a function that takes in a vector and returns the maximum and minimum values.

```
 x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

minmax<- function(x){
 minimum<- min(x)
 maximum<- max(x)

 return(c(min(x),max(x))
}
```

why does my code say
Error in return(minimum, maximum) :
multi-argument returns are not permitted

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stl you can traverse till the end of the vector by initialsing min_till_now=INT_MAX and max_till_now=INT_MIN